# Setting state with React Context from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

Hey y'all I am trying to use the Context API to manage state to render a badge where the it's not possible to pass props. Currently I am trying to use the `setUnreadNotif` setter, but it seems because I am using it in a method that loops through an array that it is not working as expected. I have been successful updating the boolean when only calling `setUnreadNotif(true/false);` alone so I know it works. I have tried many other approaches unsuccessfully and this seems the most straight forward. My provider is wrapping app appropriately as well so I know its not that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Here is my Context**

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  useContext,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import { getContentCards } from 'ThisProject/src/utils/braze';
import { ContentCard } from 'react-native-appboy-sdk';

export interface NotificationsContextValue {
  unreadNotif: boolean;
  setUnreadNotif: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

export const defaultNotificationsContextValue: NotificationsContextValue = {
  unreadNotif: false,
  setUnreadNotif: (prevState: SetStateAction<boolean>) => prevState,
};

const NotificationsContext = createContext<NotificationsContextValue>(
  defaultNotificationsContextValue,
);

function NotificationsProvider<T>({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<T>) {
  const [unreadNotif, setUnreadNotif] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <NotificationsContext.Provider
      value={{
        unreadNotif,
        setUnreadNotif,
      }}>
      {children}
    </NotificationsContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useNotifications(): NotificationsContextValue {
  const context = useContext(NotificationsContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useUser must be used within NotificationsContext');
  }

  return context;
}

export { NotificationsContext, NotificationsProvider, useNotifications };
```

**Child Component**

```
export default function NotificationsPage({
  navigation,
}: {
  navigation: NavigationProp<StackParamList>;
}) {
  const [notificationCards, setNotificationCards] = useState<
    ExtendedContentCard[]
  >([]);
  const user = useUser();
  const { setUnreadNotif } = useNotifications();

  
  const getCards = (url: string) => {
    if (url.includes('thisproject:')) {
      Linking.openURL(url);
    } else {
      navigation.navigate(ScreenIdentifier.NotificationsStack.id, {
        screen: ScreenIdentifier.NotificationsWebView.id,
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        params: {
          uri: `${getTrustedWebAppUrl()}${url}`,
          title: 'Profile',
        },
      });
    }

    getContentCards((response: ContentCard[]) => {
      response.forEach((card) => {
        if (card.clicked === false) {
          setUnreadNotif(true);
        }
      });
    });

    Braze.requestContentCardsRefresh();
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        {notificationCards?.map((item: ExtendedContentCard) => {
          return (
            <NotificationCard
              onPress={getCards}
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              description={item.cardDescription}
              image={item.image}
              clicked={item.clicked}
              ctaTitle={item.domain}
              url={item.url}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

**Fixed Issue**
I was able to fix the issue by foregoing the `forEach` and using a `findIndex` instead like so:

```
getContentCards((response: ContentCard[]) => {
      response.findIndex((card) => {
        if (card.clicked === false) {
          setUnreadNotif(true);
        }
        setUnreadNotif(false);
      });
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you saying that `getContentCards` isn't working as you expect it to?

Comment: Hey @DrewReese no the `getContentCards` is working as expected, meaning that I logged and can print whether each card is “clicked” or not. The issue is that when a card has not been clicked it is not executing the `setUnreadNotif`. When I test just firing the `setUnreadNotif` on a test button click it changes the state accordingly.

Comment: If `getContentCards` is working as expected then where is `setUnreadNotif` being called in response to anything being clicked?

Comment: My guess is that the callback for `getContentCards` is not firing, or it is firing and the array of cards is empty, or the array is populated but the data is incorrect and `card.clicked` is always true.

Have you tried using the debugger to debug the execution of that `forEach` call, to see what's actually happening in it?

Comment: thank you @Nathan & @DrewReese. I got the outcome I was looking for by using the `findIndex` prototype rather than the `forEach` I realized after your first response Drew that it was in fact doing what I was asking but I wasnt handling the instance if all cards were `card.clicked === true`. I updated my question to reflect the change.

Comment: Ah, I understand, however I would recommend a cleaner approach, since you're using `findIndex` in a way it wasn't intended to. Use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if some card is not clicked, and set the state conditionally. So: `if (response.some(card => card.clicked === false)) { setUndreadNotif(true) } else { setUnreadNotif(false) }`

Comment: This also has the benefit of being more efficient, as it short circuts-- it doesn't go through the full list, it sets unread when the first non-clicked card is detected.

Comment: Actually, your `findIndex` implementation has a serious bug-- it only tests the last card in the list. If one of the middle cards was not clicked it would set the notification to true temporarily, but the final card (which might be clicked) would clobber the state and set it to false.

Comment: Actually looking at it more, it always set the state to false (it may temporarily set to to true), since `setUnreadNotif(false);` Isn't in an `else` block. Just use the `response.some(card => card.clicked === false)` solution, it should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

An issue I see in the `getContentCards` handler is that it is mis-using the [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method to issue unintended side-effects, the effect here being enqueueing a state update.

```
getContentCards((response: ContentCard[]) => {
  response.findIndex((card) => {
    if (card.clicked === false) {
      setUnreadNotif(true);
    }
    setUnreadNotif(false);
  });
});
```

What's worse is that because the passed predicate function, e.g. the callback, never returns true, so each and every element in the `response` array is iterated and a state update is enqueued and only the enqueued state update when `card.clicked === false` evaluates true is the `unreadNotif` state set true, all other enqueued updates set it false. It may be true that the condition is true for an element, but if it isn't the *last* element of the array then any subsequent iteration is going to enqueue an update and set `unreadNotif` back to false.

The gist it seems is that you want to set the `unreadNotif` true if there is *some* element with a falsey `card.clicked` value.

```
getContentCards((response: ContentCard[]) => {
  setUnreadNotif(response.some(card => !card.clicked));
});
```

Here you'll see that the [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method returns a boolean if *any* of the array elements return true from the predicate function.

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array
> passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true
> if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function
> returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

So long as there is *some* card in the `response` that has *not* been clicked, the state will be set true, otherwise it is set to false.